# Android Parse, can sign up and sign out, but cannot login

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, authentication

I am new to apps development, I build my login and sign up page by referring to [here](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/). But the difference is I split my login and sign up page into two different activity files and xml files. I can sign up, can sign out, but cannot sign in. I wonder my coding isn't complete enough to make the login function retrieve user's information from my parse database. But after flip through internet for 3 days, I still cannot find a solution. I need you all's help on this. The code attaches here is my starting page's login button listener.

`

```
   email_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_input);
   editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

   Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 String email = email_input.getText().toString();

                 String password = editText.getText().toString();

                // Send data to Parse.com for verification
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(email,password,
                        new LogInCallback() {
                            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                if (user != null) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                            starting_page.this,
                                            MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Successfully logged in",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                            "No such user exist, please signup",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

    }
});`
```

My button1 in starting_page will link user to the register page and user will sign up themselves at there. Here is my register page's sign up button's listener.

```
name_input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_input);
    email_input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_input);
    handphoneNo_input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.handphoneNo_input);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    Button signup_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
    signup_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View a) {

            name = name_input.getText().toString();
            email = email_input.getText().toString();
            handphoneNo = handphoneNo_input.getText().toString();
            password = editText.getText().toString();

                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.setUsername(name);
                user.setEmail(email);
                user.put("handphone_num", handphoneNo);
                user.setPassword(password);
                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if(e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully sign up.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    register.this,
                                    MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sign Up error.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        }
    });
```

Comment: You want to check whether the entered email address and password matches with the User details stored in database or not.

Comment: For login use username and password.

Comment: KCN, ya, can give a clue how to did that? thanks in advance.

Comment: @SianChiewSee: you enter the name you used to register the user instead of the email-id, i wrote the answer below

Comment: @user3069305 , but why can't using e-mail address to login?

Comment: @user3069305, thanks, I didn't edit my coding, but once I fill in username instead of e-mail address, I login successfully. Thank you very much. I am the newby at here, since this question is solved did I need to do anything like close question or whatever action?

Comment: @SianChiewSee: I have posted the solution as answer, select the tick to mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In parse for logging in, you have to enter the name and password used to register the user, not email-id and password. so instead of entering emailid in the login page enter the name of the user

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10860264)

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya: In parse inorder to login you have to enter the username and password, not emailid and password, there is no need to change the code, just need to enter username instead of email id